# how to redirect on php

Tags: javascript, php

If I log out of a tab in another browser, I want to be redirected to the login page.

so, wrote the php code

```php
if (!$_SESSION['isLoggedIn']) {
    header('go to login in page')
    return;
}
```

However, browser only makes a http request to the login page, but does not go to the actual login page.

and js

```
function tick() {
    ...

    // $.cookie( 'session_timeout' )) === 600sec(default)
    if (parseInt(localStorage['session_timeout']) > parseInt($.cookie( 'session_timeout' ))) {
        window.location.href = 'go to log in page';
    } else {
        localStorage['session_timeout']++;
    }

    ...
}

setInterval(() => tick(), 1000)
```

another redirect login is none.
I want to redirect to the login page when the session expires on request.

how to redict?

I compared cookies to receiving them from php.

Comment: Have a look at the storage events in javascript and listen to them. The current solution looks like a workaround to me.

Comment: All I want to log out of the other tabs(tab2) in the browser and go to the login page if I send a request from the remaining tabs(tab1).

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question is quite unclear - are `header('go to login in page')` and `window.location.href = 'go to log in page';` pseudo-code, or do you literally have those in your code?  "*browser only makes a http request to the login page, but does not go to the actual login page*" - what does this mean, exactly, what did you see?

There are plenty of examples of using PHP to redirect here ([here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php)) and [in the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the header function with the Location header to specify the URL of the login page like this.

```
if (!$_SESSION['isLoggedIn']) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    return;
}
```

and then  if you want to redirect to the login page when the session expires, you can modify the tick function to check if the session has expired and redirect accordingly.

```
function tick() {
    if (parseInt(localStorage['session_timeout'])> 
        parseInt($.cookie('session_timeout'))) {
        window.location.href = 'login.php';
    } else {
        localStorage['session_timeout']++;
    }

    //...
}

setInterval(() => tick(), 1000);
```

You have to implement proper session management and expiration handling on the server-side as well.